# How to get selected row details in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I don't know how to get the selected row details in jQuery. For example, I select first two rows in my table.

I want to submit to next page, and the second page can shows the selected two row.

[image: This is the picture of selected row]

And here is the coding for my second page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#card-type').html(simpleStorage.get('cardType'));
//my code stuck here.
```

Anyone can give me some ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that without a php server

Comment: I'm using html and jQuery to do that. Still thinking about php sir.

Comment: The second page needs to have the DOM structure you're coding for. That is, it should have the row selector HTML to target it via jQuery. Otherwise, the only other option is using cookies or localStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said @krushna, you can try to use localStorage.

I never use it before but i wanted try for your needs.

Here is my solution, of course, you can improve it, i only give a way to solve your problem.
This following code works for your need :

First, my page **p1.html**

**The html :** 
I just try to replicate your html from your picture.

```
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Primary</th>
        <th>Tag/untag</th>
        <th>Account</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" class="primary" name="rd_prim" id="rd_prim1" ></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="tag" id="check_1"></td>
        <td><span class="account" id="acc1">123456789</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" class="primary" name="rd_prim" id="rd_prim2" ></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="tag" id="check_2" ></td>
         <td><span class="account" id="acc2">987654321</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="smt">
  </body>
```

**The Jquery :**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      localStorage.clear();
      $("#smt").click(function() {
        var data_length = $('table').find("tr").not(":first").length-1;
        var i = 0;
        localStorage.setItem("data_length", data_length);
        $.each($('table').find("tr").not(":first"), function() {
            $.each($(this).find("td"),function() {
                if ($(this).children().is("span")) {
                  localStorage.setItem($(this).children().attr("class")+""+i,  $(this).children().text());
                } else {
                  localStorage.setItem($(this).children().attr("class")+""+i,  $(this).children().is(":checked"));
                }
            })      
        i++;
        })
        window.location = "p2.html";
      })
    })
```

And now the second page : **p2.html** Edited

**The html :**

```
<body>
    <div id="result">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Primary</th>
                <th>Accounts</th>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**The JQuery :**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var data_length = localStorage.getItem("data_length");
        for (var i = 0; i <= data_length; i++) {
            var primary = localStorage.getItem("primary"+i) == "true"?"checked":"";
            var tag = localStorage.getItem("tag"+i) == "true" ?"true":"false";
            var account = localStorage.getItem("account"+i);
            if (tag != "true" ) {
                continue;
            }
            $("table").append("<tr><td><input type='radio' name='rd_prim' "+primary+"></td><td><span class='account'>"+account+"</span></td></tr>");
        }
  })
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes sir, it works as what I want to do. How about if the p2.html is show the table with the checked button?

Comment: What do you mean ? I dont't understand what you want on p2.html

Comment: After we check in p1.html, p2.html will shows the table, together with the 'checked' box result.

Comment: What will be the difference with the table on p1.html?

Comment: p1.html enable user to check the check box and submit. p2.html will only shows the table(check box) with user checked.

Comment: i edited jquery/html from p2.html, hope this is what you need.

Comment: Yes. Thank you sir